# How to disable some options of a mat-select depending on a date-picker?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am using a mat-datepicker to select a day and then a mat-select to select a time:

```
<div class = "date-picker">
      <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>Select date</mat-label>
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [(ngModel)]="date" name = "date" [matDatepickerFilter]="dateFilter">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
        <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <div class ="time-picker">
      <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
        <mat-label>Select time</mat-label>
        <mat-select [(ngModel)]="time" name = "time">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let time of selectableTime" [value]="time" [disabled]="disableTimes(time)">{{time}} </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
```

In my .ts file I have:

```
selectableTime = [8, 8.30, 9, 9.30, 10, 10.30, 11, 11.30, 12, 12.30, 14, 14.30, 15, 15.30, 16, 16.30, 17, 17.30, 18, 18.30]

disableTimes(time): boolean{
    for(let i = 0; i < this.timesToDisable.length; i++ ){
      if(this.timesToDisable[i] === time){
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
```

This disableTimes works properly, but what I want is to disable a time in mat-select depending on the date selected.
So let's say if I select 7 July and it has already a booking at 10 o'clock, '10' should be disabled in mat-select.

I already have the array of dates which has bookings:

```
datesWithBookings: Date[] = [];
```